# How do i remove value from any tag in XML

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing

How do I remove value from any tag in xml. For e.g i have a xml like below:

```
<Property>
    <Name>Trip</Name>
    <Value>123456</Value>
    <Visible>false</Visible>
    <Enabled>false</Enabled>
    <ValidValues>
      <ValidValue>
        <Value>1SDA</Value>
        <DisplayValue>Ekip M</DisplayValue>
        <Assignable>false</Assignable>
      </ValidValue>           
    </ValidValues>
  </Property>
```

I want to remove the value 123456 and  make it like:

```
<Property>
        <Name>Trip</Name>
        <Value />
        <Visible>false</Visible>
        <Enabled>false</Enabled>
        <ValidValues>
          <ValidValue>
            <Value>1SDA</Value>
            <DisplayValue>Ekip M</DisplayValue>
            <Assignable>false</Assignable>
          </ValidValue>           
        </ValidValues>
      </Property>
```

I tried to loop through the xml to find the value and pass empty like this

```
childNode("Value").InnerText = ""
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

Need help here. Thanks

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Which language are you using?

Comment: It is better to use XSLT for the task. Are you open to it?

Comment: Ok, I can try XSLT. I am open to all possible solutions

Answer (score 0):

So I like XElement.  Here is an answer.

```
    Dim someXML As XElement
    someXML = XElement.Load("path goes here")

    'use literal for testing
    someXML = <Property>
                  <Name>Trip</Name>
                  <Value>123456</Value>
                  <Visible>false</Visible>
                  <Enabled>false</Enabled>
                  <ValidValues>
                      <ValidValue>
                          <Value>1SDA</Value>
                          <DisplayValue>Ekip M</DisplayValue>
                          <Assignable>false</Assignable>
                      </ValidValue>
                  </ValidValues>
              </Property>

    someXML.<Value>.Value = ""
    Stop
```

Resulting XML

```
<Property>
  <Name>Trip</Name>
  <Value></Value>
  <Visible>false</Visible>
  <Enabled>false</Enabled>
  <ValidValues>
    <ValidValue>
      <Value>1SDA</Value>
      <DisplayValue>Ekip M</DisplayValue>
      <Assignable>false</Assignable>
    </ValidValue>
  </ValidValues>
</Property>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers.

But
`someXML.<Value>.Value = ""`  --> This did not work for me. but apparently

`childNode("Value").InnerText = Nothing`  worked for me. 

We can close this thread. Thanks all

Comment: @user3177025 - The code I posted works.